# Android Layout Division

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to divide my screen in two parts,I have a `LinearLayout` and it contains two `LinearLayouts` again.

How to divide these two `LinearLayouts` into two equal parts?

Comment: just read your responses to the answers.  Let me know .. how do you want to divide them? Vertically (Stacked on Top of each other) or Horizontally (Appearing on the sides of each other)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

to both of them. The `layout_weight` parameter being equal distributes the amount of space evenly.

Work on accepting some of the answers to your previous questions, as well.

Comment: HI Thanks for the solution, but i couldn't get the two layouts divided, i have hardcoded layout_width value as 200px, i dont want to do like this, please suggest with example

Comment: This is how you do it. If you want to hardcode your width, then of course it won't scale to 50%. Change it to fill_parent.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I use android:layout_weight="1" for this. Also you can use a table layout.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this example helps you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootlinearlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et01"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="First TextBox"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et02"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Another TextBox"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, i want to divide the screen vertically in to two, i have used your code, the "AnotherTextbox " is coming very after the "First Text box", i want a 50% to the first and 50% to the second.Any suggestions ?

Comment: Try android:layout_height="match_parent" in both the EditTexts. This should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

we can use 
`android:layout_width="0dp"` and
`android:layout_weight="1"` for both of fragment
and in parent of these, we can use `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`